# Paragraphs: referenced entity error on save

Tags: 8, paragraphs

I recently updated to Drupal 8.6.2 and Paragraphs 8.x-1.3.

I have a content type with a Paragraphs field. When I try to update an existing node I get the following error message:

`The referenced entity (user: 21) does not exist.`

- The existing paragraphs do not reference users directly.
- User 21 does not exist.
- User 21 is not the node author.
- I can only update the node if delete *all* of the paragraphs, of every type.
- There are no pending db updates or entity updates.

My feeling is that something didn't update correctly, but I'm not sure how to check / rerun the updates. (There were a number of updates to be run when I deployed the 8.6.2 update.)

*UPDATE:* I rolled back to the previous release and DB state, and I *still* get the error (which no one noticed), so it is not related to the update.

*UPDATE 2:* [Ticket on drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs/issues/2994286)

Comment: You may need to make sure you have the latest version of the entity reference revisions module.  I think there was problem with translations and ownership that has been resolved.  This might be related.

Comment: @CGMonroe I updated entity reference revisions when I updated paragraphs. My feeling is that the update didn't go smoothly, but I'm not sure where.

Comment: I know its tedious, but have you dug through the paragraph tables in the DB and looked for a reference to User 21? It may help shed a bit of light on whats happening.

Comment: Yes, I would do the same. Probably you need to check only the paragraphs of this node, because the error is clearly a validation error of a subform in this node form.

Answer (score 1):

User 21 was deleted, but `21` was still stored as the value in the `uid` column of the paragraphs tables. Changing the uid to that of an existing user (23) solved the problem:

```
UPDATE paragraphs_item_field_data SET uid = 23 WHERE uid = 21;
UPDATE paragraphs_item_revision SET revision_uid = 23 WHERE revision_uid = 21;
UPDATE paragraphs_item_revision_field_data SET uid = 23 WHERE uid = 21;
```

Run SQL, empty cache, reload edit page.

Note: other tables also contain the uid 21, but without a (noticeable) adverse effect.

```
UPDATE file_managed SET uid = 23 where uid = 21;
UPDATE node_field_data SET uid = 23 where uid = 21;
UPDATE node_field_revision SET uid = 23 where uid = 21;
UPDATE node_revision SET revision_uid = 23 where revision_uid = 21;
```

And two from contrib:

```
UPDATE crop_revision SET revision_uid = 23 where revision_uid = 21;
UPDATE redirect SET uid = 23 where uid = 21;
```